# Why is my Razor page route link not working in Dotnet 6 Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When i create a dummy razor page using dotnet 6 framework and navigate to the route i.e "https://localhost:7063/dummy" in the browser, it returns a 404 page..Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong.

the page model is dummy.cshtml.cs and looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace myWebApp.Pages
{
    public class dummyModel : PageModel
    {
        public void OnGet()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The dummy.cshtml page looks like this:

```
@page 
@model dummyModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Dummy page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome to Dummy Page</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="">Doing something dummy</a>.</p>
</div>
```

and the folder structure looks like this

[image: folder structure]

the program.cs file has content as such:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: Can you share your Program.cs?

Comment: @YiyiYou..I have updated the question to include the program.cs..please, check it out ..Thanks

Comment: you need `@page "/dummy"`

Comment: I tried that before and have tried again with no luck.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am migrating from .net core 3.1 to ,net 6. If anybody can has any solution please do let me know.